# Load data: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Tags: python, pandas, sentiment-analysis

I am currently working on a sentiment analysis project. When I was trying to load data, the error`TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` appears. So I modified the str to an int. However, now the error `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>` appears. How can I solve this error?
The data type = dtype('O')

```
import pandas as pd
#read data
review_df = pd.read_csv( '/Users/mhnwong/Desktop/FYP potential/metropark_trans_demoji.csv')
#create label
review_df["is_bad_review"] = int(review_df["rate"]).apply(lambda x:1 if x <= 8 else 0)
# select only relevant columns
review_df = review_df[["review","is_bad_review"]]

review_df.head()
```

Data:
[This is the data I have got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDHa0.png)

Comment: Can you paste the content of `metropark_trans_demoji.csv` file? This might help us solve your problem.

Comment: Can you try `review_df["is_bad_review"] = review_df["rate"].apply(lambda x:1 if int(x) <= 8 else 0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your `rate` column in `metropark_trans_demoji.csv` file contain something that doesn't belong to numbers?

You should make sure that the content of the `rate` column can all be converted to `int` first.

Suppose the `rate` column's data all belong to `int`, then you can write

```
review_df["is_bad_review"] = review_df["rate"].apply(lambda x:1 if int(x) <= 8 else 0)
```

This converts the content of the `rate` column to `int`, then compares it with 8.

The type of `review_df["rate"]` is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. It cannot be converted to `int` directly.

Comment: I have tried but it return TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: I've changed my answer. Could you try the new one?

Comment: What is the return value of `type(review_df["rate"])`?

Comment: I guess `type(review_df["rate"])` is of type `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`.

Comment: Yes the type is pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: Then how can I convert it to int

Comment: `pandas.core.series.Series` can't be converted to `int`. I guess it is the `x` that should be converted to `int`. Do you have anything in `rate` column that doesn't belong to `int`? For example, `"45"`, `6.7`, `"---"` ?

Comment: Yes cuz the rate is have one decimal e.g. 8.4

Comment: Then what should i do to continue

Comment: How about converting to float? `review_df["is_bad_review"] = review_df["rate"].apply(lambda x:1 if float(x) <= 8 else 0)`

Comment: I think it cannot be converted to float either